# Wondering what "there they were" mean

Tags: word-meaning

> the party, I snuck to where everyone put their shoes. My heart was
>   thudding, not only from the anticipation of what I was about to do,
>   but also fear of getting caught. **There they were**! Her UGG boots in all
>   their beauty. I carefully treaded over and for a few minutes I was
>   scared to approach.

Comment: It just means "They (the shoes) were there".

Answer (score 1):

This is the best example of **why everybody asks for the context**. You should have just mentioned it and it would have been a lot easier to answer this.

The phrase is taken from the forum where a person is describing his experience of a **foot fetish**.

Here is that part of the [story](http://ca.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091109200501AAPsZlR) -

> Hi, I just had the most amazing, unreal experience of my life and I needed to share it. So for my whole life, I've had a major foot/shoe fetish for girls feet. I've always had fantasies about licking, sniffing, kissing or sucking a girl's feet or shoes or boots w/e they're wearing. So the other day, my fantasy was finally satisifed (for the moment). I have a cousin the same age as me. We had a family gathering and she showed up. She looked dazzling in her UGG boots. I really wanted to worship those boots when I saw her in them. Now, I know I couldn't just ask if I could go and worship her feet/boots so during the party, I snuck to where everyone put their shoes. My heart was thudding, not only from the anticipation of what I was about to do, but also fear of getting caught. **There they were! Her UGG boots in all their beauty.** I carefully treaded over and for a few minutes, I was too scared to approach, fearing someone might be somehow watching.

**Clearly, they were the UGG boots.**